# Most efficient way to perform large scale JSONB replace in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have almost 2 million records that need a simple string replacement done on a value within the identifiers array of something like this partial record

```
    {
      "id": "a851375d-f6a0-4fba-ba69-c584901de73c",
      "source": "MARC",
      "title": "Voice Content and Usability [electronic resource] / So, Preston.",
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "value": "9781952616020",
          "identifierTypeId": "fcca2643-406a-482a-b760-7a7f8aec640e"
        },
        {
          "value": "(CaSebORM)9781098128852",
          "identifierTypeId": "7e591197-f335-4afb-bc6d-a6d76ca3bace"
        },
        {
          "value": "5429852",
          "identifierTypeId": "d5989db8-ddc3-4f06-a465-73e99ec262d3"
        },
        {
          "value": "ocm00000001saf9781098128852",
          "identifierTypeId": "7e591197-f335-4afb-bc6d-a6d76ca3bace"
        }
]
}
```

I need to detect and remove the "ocm0000000" from the final value, and I'm looking for the most efficient way to do it. When I attempted to simply cast jsonb onto string, do a simple string replacement e.g.

```
update my.table
set jsonb = REPLACE(jsonb::text, 'ocm0000000', '')::jsonb
```

it took the CPU through the roof and took all the connections for our RDS cluster interfering with other operations making it necessary to kill the process.

What is the best approach for making this sort of replacement when so many rows are affected?

Comment: "took all the connections"  That is not a believable claim.  UPDATE statements do not spontaneously spawn new connections.  (Currently, they don't even use parallelization).  What did you see in your monitoring that makes you think this?

Comment: The DB admins contacted me to tell me. When I looked at monitoring, I saw a spike from about 30 IOPS to > 50,000 IOPS sustained and other transactions in the system for other users were not getting through -- presumably those are the hanging connections. When I killed my PID, those other transactions occurred, IOPs dropped back to normal, and things were as before. In any case, I'm wondering what the best way to solve a data issue like this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current UPDATE will rewrite every row, even ones that don't need to be changed.  You should add a WHERE clause to prevent that.  This is especially important if you want to break the update up into batches.

```
set jsonb = REPLACE(jsonb::text, 'ocm0000000', '')::jsonb
where jsonb::text like '%ocm0000000%'
```

The easiest way to finish this would be to declare a maintenance window and just do it, or do it during off hours.  For me it took less than 2 minutes to update 2 million copies of your example record on a small laptop, but with SSD drives.  You said it was only partial, but I don't know how much bigger your real record would be.  Maybe you can clone our server and use that to test how long it would take.  You can also temporarily provision more IOPS to make it go faster.

If you want to run it in batches, you could add a where clause to restrict the range of ctid which will be updated:

```
set jsonb = REPLACE(jsonb::text, 'ocm0000000', '')::jsonb 
where jsonb::text like '%ocm0000000%' 
and ctid between '(0,0)' and '(9999,99)'; --first ~80MB.
```

Then you would wait for the system to catch its breath, then repeat with the CTID window slid farther down.  Repeat until the whole table has been covered.  You should only have to go until the first number in the ctid is as great as the current pages in the table.  Then run it one more time without the ctid condition, to make sure nothing slipped by.

Comment: The awful thing about this particular query is it affects almost every row so lack of WHERE is deliberate. But running it in batches is what I was looking for -- and then I can use the WHERE to avoid scanning everything. Your answer makes me realize another mechanism I could use is a temp table listing the ids with a sequence number to control how many are processed at a time

Comment: Note that the CTID range scan will scan the entire table each time, until V14 when it learns how to do better.  It won't change the chunks outside that region, but will still read them.  So it will lead to write IO being done in smaller batches, but read IO will be done over and over and over again, so it may be even worse that the original if the problem is not just write IO but rather all IO.  You could perhaps pick some indexed user column (not CTID) to do the range scan on to get more efficient reading.